# change maps for cv::remap to include resize

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I remove the distortion from my images with `cv::remap()`. The necessary maps are created with `cv::initUndistortRectifyMap()`. Now I'd like to also resize the images and if possible I want to include this in my maps such that `cv::remap()` would remove the distortion and resize the images at once.

Is there an easy way to change the maps such that they do the two task at the same time? I have to change the maps and can't compute them from scratch since I don't have the input parameters from `cv::initUndistortRectifyMap()` anymore.

I could just calculate every entry myself, but I was hopping for different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV does offer some functions which calculate the maps for cv::remap()

1. InitUndistortRectigyMap()
2. warpAffine()
3. warpPerspective()

However, none of these can be used to combine two transforms. The only chance to use them together is to build your custom function. Looking at the code for warpAffine - which can be used to resize an image, can give you some help in the task.